# Loading script within a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling with the best ways to load a responsive / mobile page, and then I found a jQuery plugin that uncomment things depending on the screen width. I found it perfect since I wouldn't need extra HTTP requests and for the mobile user it will be faster.

But, I stumbled on a problem: this jQuery plugin cannot load / render other scripts. You can see in this fiddle I just did: https://jsfiddle.net/g3f88q5k/

```
<div id="Test">
<!-- @media only all and (min-width:400px)
<script> Whatever </script>   
-->
</div>
```

It uncomments the section I wanted, but the script that makes the twitter a button a twitter button doesn't work.

How can I make it work, if there's any way of doing it?

Comment: Out of the box... If you are talking about responsiveness then bootstrap is today's hero..

Comment: @Reddy, bootstrap isn't an appropriate suggestion for this question, and it's not a particularly great library for large scale projects because it's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Reddy I am using it, with the hidden classes and all. But, those classes still load the content, just doesn't show. I want something to load the content depending on the screen size :)

Comment: I get your point now thanks :) ... Why don't you write a custom script which will check if the content is hidden or not and then decide which script to load...

Answer (score 0):

XHR (or JS code itself) can be made within if statements but in the case of XHR you are going to take a performance hit for multiple script loads.  You'd be better off putting all your JavaScript in one minified file and let the thing download at once.  You could have JS detect min-width, etc like the media query but probably not easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try [enquire.js](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js).

By `match` callback:

```
enquire.register("your screen media query here", {

    match : function() {
        //load your script here
    }
});
```

Comment: With enquire.js is it possible for me to load normal content or just script?

Comment: What do you mean by normal content? You can do anything that javascript can do in the callback, but seems not uncomment html, :( . So, it depends.

Comment: Like, if I want to show an image, or have "regular html" that, in some point, shows a script (the twitter button, in my case ;D)

Answer (score -1):

You can role something like this

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js";
            script.onload = function() {
                console.log($); // now it's loaded
            };

            document.body.appendChild(script);
            console.log($); // doesn't work
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm just using jquery as an example, but it should work with anything.

Comment: I don't think it would work with what I want to. This loads scripts, right, but in the case of the twitter button...?